# How to filter through controller and action within params column?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to filter through controller and action to find the record's activity:

I initially queried the record like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_activity_logs WHERE user_id= 1234;
```

It returned me this:

```
 id | user_id | ip_address | controller | action | params
__________________________________________________________
1      1234     blah          dashboard    index   {"controller"=>"dashboard","action"=>"index"}
```

What I in fact want to query is to filter through controller and action within the params column. Lets say I want to filter by specifying controller to be "users" and action to be "update".

I want to know what I can get based on these two params and a given user_id.

UPDATED: Here is the action method definition for update, but do not know if it helps. All I want is to find user_id 1234 who has "users" value for controller and "update" value for action inside params.

```
def update
    run(action: :update, model_variable: :@user) do |result|
      respond_to do |format|
        if result['success']
          format.html { redirect_to(user_edit_demographics_path(result['model'])) }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        else
          format.html do
            render action: 'select_type'
          end
          format.json do
            render json: result['model'].errors,
                   status: :unprocessable_entity
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you include an example of the current code you're using, and/or an example of your view?

Comment: Hi. I just added an update to my post for the update method definition, but not sure if that would help. Basically I used a very simple query of that user but it does not show everything. I know that if I query by filtering through controller and action inside the params, I can get what I want inside the db.

Comment: Can you include an example of the form object you're using in your view? That should help us give specific answers based on your params